# Iterating URL in a loop

Tags: python, rest

I need to carry out a GET request for each value that is returned in a variable. My variable is called `epics` and looks like this:

```
IN.D.VIX.MONTH2.IP,TM.D.ATHENS.DAILY.IP,KB.D.HEALTH.DAILY.IP,CS.D.EURSEK.TODAY.IP,CF.D.USDNOK.JUN.IP,CF.D.GBPJPY.MAR.IP,IR.D.IB.Month3.IP,IX.D.SUNFUN.DAILY.IP
```

I basically want to append one epic at a time and perform a get request e.g.

```
Request 1 
http://api.example.com/v1.14/member?id=IN.D.VIX.MONTH2.IP
Request 2
http://api.example.com/v1.14/member?id=TM.D.ATHENS.DAILY.IP
```

When I run the code below I get `TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got str`.

```
url = "http://api.example.com/v1.14/epics?id=" + str(epics)
for i in range(epics):
    print(url)
```

Comment: `for i in range(len(epics))` You need to call the `len()` function to get the length of the list when using range, this will iterate as many times that `len()` returns.

Comment: Thanks but that just appends the entire variable to the URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`range()` takes an integer argument, however your `epics` variable is presumably some kind of iterable (`list`?). If you're looking to iterate over each of the values of `epics`, you can simply reference that in your `for` loop:

```py
for epic in epics:
    url = "http://api.example.com/v1.14/epics?id=" + str(epic)
    print(url)
```